# Creating a new percentage column based on Dialect and Age Group in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

[This is an image of my dataset now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAGhH.png)

I would like to create a new column that holds percentages based on Dialect and Age Group. For example, the percentage for Cantonese aged 0-19 should be [72709 / (72709 + 112149 + 133188 + 70825)] *100 = 18.697%. I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add some data in the form of a dput() output, but I think this should do it

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(Dialect) %>%
  mutate(percent = value /sum(value) * 100)
```